# If one buys clothing or jewelry for his wife for simchas Yom-Tov, and she wears them on Shabbos before YT, and again on YT, is he מקיים the mitzvah?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov

If someone buys new clothing or jewelry for his wife for Yom-Tov, in order to observe his חיוב (obligation) of Simchas Yom-Tov, and Shabbos was the day before Yom-Tov, (as the upcoming Shavuos), and she wears the clothing / jewelry on Shabbos before YT, and then again on YT, is it still considered simchas YT, even though she already wore it before?

[If it is, What if Shabbos was a few days/weeks... before YT? how far can it go?)

[See K'dushin 34b-35a - אשה בעלה משמחה, A woman, her husband must make her happy (for simchas Yom tov), and שולחן ערוך סימן תקכט סעיף ב  **והנשים, קונה להן בגדים ותכשיטין**; [for] women, their husband should buy for them clothes and jewelry...]

Comment: Presumably it depends on whether she is still enjoying the newness of it?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons - So if he gave it for her for Pesach, and she wore it on Pesach for the first time, and put it away, and then wore it again on Shvuos, and she is still enjoying the newness of it, he would be yotze the mitzvah twice, with the same peice of jewelry without giving her anything for shavuos?

Comment: an interesting thought. possibly. my initial comment is more thinking aloud, or I'd put it as an answer.